# Is it possible to unload a fetched JSON file from a web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, memory-management, unload

I have a web application that loads very large JSON files via the fetch() api, but there does not seem to be a way to clear them from memory when the program no longer needs them. Is there a method of dynamically unloading fetched files from system memory to prevent poor performance? I am aware that resetting the variable clears the JSON from it, but the file still lingers in memory.
The method I am using to get JSON files is simply `var JSONvar = fetch(http://api.website.com/files/JSONfile.json)`

I have tried searching online for any solutions and have come across methods for unloading/reloading javascript files (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388025/is-it-possible-to-unload-javascript)) directly embedded in the HTML document, but I do not believe a similar method exists for JSON loaded into javascript variables. I am aware that window.onunload exists, but I am not sure how to force anything to unload.

Comment: How do you know that *the file still lingers in memory*? JavaScript is a garbage-collection environment.

Comment: It's mostly a hypothesis at the moment, but when I watch the RAM usage of firefox in the windows task manager it continues to climb whenever I make another request. the cache is disabled, and the memory resets if I reload the page. I will do some more experiments, as I was unaware that js was a garbage collector environment, thank you.

Comment: @Tal Rofe Yes that answers my question! thank you!